# Racket Scheme - Write Character Stream to FIle

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to implement a stream->file function that takes a stream of characters and prints it to a file. I feel I am close to a solution, but cannot figure out how to complete this.

```
(define stream->file
  (lambda (filename str)
    (let ((output (open-output-file filename)))
      (letrec
          ((build-output-stream
            (lambda (str)
              (let ((char (write-char (stream-first str) output)))
                (if (eof-object? char)
                    (begin
                      (close-output-port output)
                      empty-stream)
                  (stream-cons char (build-output-stream (stream-rest str))))))))
        (build-output-stream str)))))
```

This doesn't do anything other than say `#<stream>` in the output. It creates a file, but does not write to it. What am I missing?

Comment: What's in your stream? Also, If I'm right, there is no reason to use the `stream-cons` and return `empty-stream`. It would make more sense to return the `output`. `letrec` is also unncessary, you can used a named let instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code overly complicated. You need to write each element in the stream and since this is pure side effect you might as well use `stream-for-each`. Instead of doing the file port handling it's easier to use `with-output-to-file` since it will close the port when the `thunk` is done. This is the result:

```
(define (stream->file file-path stream)
  (with-output-to-file file-path
    (thunk (stream-for-each display stream))))

(stream->file "test-stream.txt" (stream #\t #\e #\s #\t #\newline))
; undefined, makes a file named "test-stream.txt" with the content "test\n"
```